# windows 8 upgrade to a already partitioned drive

Tags: windows

I have a partitioned hard drive running windows 7. Will upgrading to windows 8 keep my partitions as they are? C is my administrator and D is where I search the web and store files. Will this stay the same after upgrade to 8

Comment: Can  you clarify what "Administrator" means in your question? C is where you have Windows installed and D is for data?   Or?

Comment: @Voyger - An upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8 saves ALL personal settings, personal files, and supported installed applications

Comment: Provided that you remain on the same bit level (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, everything will be save. Your files, partitions, apps etc. will be save. The upgrade from windows 7 to 8 is really just an **upgrade**.

If you would upgrade from XP or Vista, than you have to install your apps etc. again.